# get only a string from foreach/select result

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\hs-source.txt' -list  '\bhttp\:\/\/www\.hs\-scene\.to\/wbb4\/index\.php\/Thread\/(?:(?!Neuerscheinungen)(?:.|\n))*Neuerscheinungen-((?:Jan(?:uar)?|Feb(?:ruar)?|Mär(?:z)?|Apr(?:il)?|Mai|Jun(?:i)?|Jul(?:i)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Okt(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dez(?:ember)?))(-20\d{2})'  | foreach-object  {$_.matches} | select value
```

give me this result:

```
Value
----                                                                      
http://www.hs-scene.to/wbb4/index.php/Thread/42042-H%C3%B6rbuch-Neuerscheinungen-August-2015
```

how can i get only the link, without value and the strokes?
I want to use the link in the next part of my script.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the final pipe command to:

```
| select -ExpandProperty value
```

Otherwise `value` remains a *property* of the object, it just happens it's the only property you're selecting. You would need to access it with `$obj.value` without the `-ExpandProperty` switch